# How to send HTML email with Image using asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi all of you I try following code to send HTML email along with Image in HTML
but I can receive only text format mail not Image

```
public void HTML_mail(string mailTo,string mailSub,string mailMessage)
    {
        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            //client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            //client.Port = 587;


            //WITH SMTP Server with Authenticaton
            client.Host = mailServer;
            client.Port = Convert.ToInt16(serverPort);

            // setup Smtp authentication
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
                new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = credentials;

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(userName);
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(mailTo));

            msg.Subject = mailSub;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            msg.Body = string.Format(mailMessage);
            //HTML CODE "<html><head></head><body><p><h3>Dadu</h3></p><img src='http://localhost:2727/photo/mukeshwedsjashmin/1/Suresh2.jpg' height='500px' width='500px' alt='' /></body>"
            try
            {
                client.Send(msg);
                //lblMsg.Text = "Your message has been successfully sent.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //lblMsg.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                //lblMsg.Text = "Error occured while sending your message." + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I can Only see the "Dadu" in the mail
I choose display Image on my gmail A/C

Comment: Another option is to append HTML document as an attachment and to use only text in the body of the mail.

Answer (score 1):

You're email is referencing a localhost image, try it wih an online one as the image may not be available to the email.

Comment: If My web Application on internet then it is posilbe to send email with Image as I need

Comment: @Dadu think of it like this: You send someone a letter via snail mail and tell them "The picture is in a frame on the second floor of *this* house." They get the letter, but they don't know exactly what you mean by this house, they're thinking "my house doesn't even have a second floor!". Instead, what you should do is provide them with the address of the house (an IP address or registered domain name) so they know where to get the image. Alternatively, include the image in the mail itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your email is referencing a local image:

```
http://localhost:2727/photo/mukeshwedsjashmin/1/Suresh2.jpg
```

The only e-mail receiver that will be able to see that image is yourself. No one else will have access to your local web server, thus won't be able to see the image.

You need to reference an image that is available to the public.

**As a side note**

In my experience, sending emails like this from a local mail server, especially if the email contain HTML and images, will almost certainly be caught as spam. I prefer to send my emails through an email delivery service. I only have experience with [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com/), which has a good .Net library, but I bet there are other great services as well.